# How to not run else-statement in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning Postgres. When I'm not writing down else-statement my table returns nothing. I'm trying to render all users when boolean is false.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
JOIN posts p
ON u.id = p.author_id
    AND CASE WHEN true   // if true then render u.id = 5
        THEN  u.id = 5
        ELSE  ???        // else render all users
    END
```

Comment: #scottsf - you can deduct the else part

Comment: What does render do? If you want to limit results to a specific `id` in `users` you can remove the part after `p.author_id` and add `WHERE u.id = 5`

Comment: @ZakirHossain - I tried to deduct the else part, but my table returned nothing.

Comment: @scottsf - you should show your table and required table...

Answer (score 0):

A simple `AND/ OR` with proper parentheses is clear and better than a `CASE` expression to check such combination of conditions in `WHERE` clause / `ON` part of JOINs

```
SELECT * FROM users u
  JOIN posts p
ON u.id = p.author_id AND 
(
   ( some_condition = true AND u.id = 5 )
OR   some_condition = false
 );
```